# Get line numbers for lines with empty fields

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a large pipe-delimited file where I need to find the line number of all lines where a certain field is empty.

I can use `cut -d \| -f 6 filename.txt` to output just that column.

What is a utility/tool/command I can use to find what output lines from the above are empty?

Comment: What do you mean, where a certain field is empty? Please **[Edit]** your question and add an example and the desired output. Those answering need a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# cut -d \| -f 6 test.txt | grep -v -E .\+ -n

grep 
    -v invert match
    -E .\+ match any 1+ character
    -n output line numbers
```

Comment: I actually ended up using '^$', but the -n was the missing piece for me!  Thx

Comment: Or you could just search for not-`.`.

Comment: This method prints an extra *colon* `:` after each *line number*... using: GNU grep 2.5.4

Comment: @Peter.O then use the colon as a delimiter for a cut, i.e., `cut -d \| -f 6 test.txt | grep -v -E .\+ -n | cut -d ':' -f1`

Answer (score 5):

You can combine `cut` and `grep` as others have shown, or you can use the all-purpose text filter `awk`.

```
awk -F'|' '$6 == "" {print NR}'
```

Comment: Nifty. Note for others that might come along: as written, this command takes input from stdin.  add `< filename.txt` to the end to read from the file.

Comment: @Davie Oneill:  `awk` doesn't require the file to be via a stdin redirecton `<` (which can also be before the awk command)... `awk` can natively accept input via filename(s) as its last parameter(s).

Answer (score 1):

`^` in a regular expression matches the beginning of the line, and `$` the end, so `^$` matches empty lines. `grep` takes a `-n` argument that outputs the line numbers of matching lines instead of the lines themselves, so:

```
$ grep -n '^$'
```

You can also use `-v` to invert the match and count non-matching lines, in which case you want to match lines that have at least one character (where `.` matches any character):

```
$ grep -n -v .
```

Comment: You read my question wrong: I want the line numbers, not the count.  But +1 for '^$'

Comment: @David Yeah, I actually fixed it before you commented; I reread it and realized :). [guido got it right first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15036/get-line-numbers-for-empty-lines/15039#15039)

Comment: (above comment was from when he answer contained -c instead of -n)